# Filter consecutive ones below threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a binary array and want to filter the consecutive ones below a choosable threshold. That means if there are less than e.g. 30 consecutive ones in the array, they should be set to zero.

Example:

```
import numpy as np 

array = np.zeros(365)
array[0:100] = 1
array[250:365] = 1
array[140:150] = 1
array[180:210] = 1
array[211] = 1
array[240:242] = 1

print(array)
```

After the operation, this should give me an array like:

```
import numpy as np 

array = np.zeros(365)
array[0:100] = 1
array[250:365] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [morphological opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)). Choose your favourite image-processing library, most likely it will have such a function. For example, we could use scikit-image's [`binary_opening`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.binary_opening):

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import binary_opening

# Original array
array = np.zeros(365, np.uint8)
array[0:100] = 1
array[250:365] = 1
array[140:150] = 1
array[180:210] = 1
array[211] = 1
array[240:242] = 1
print('Before: \n', array, '\n\n')

# Binary opening with structuring element [1, 1, ..., 1] 
n = 30
array = np.uint8(binary_opening(array, np.ones(n, np.uint8)))
print('After: \n', array, '\n\n')
```

The output:

```
Before: 
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 


After: 
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Please pay attention, that your proposed result is wrong, since `array[180:211] = 1` will remain for `n = 30`.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:       3.8.5
NumPy:        1.19.1
scikit-image: 0.17.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is it possible to define the axis on which the operation acts? For example, if I have a 2D-array but want 1D-binary_opening over the first axis. I mean it could be done with a for loop but that is probably slow.

Comment: @clearseplex You can set up a different structuring element like `[1, 1, ..., 1]'` (column vector instead of row vector) to get the desired behaviour for each column of an image.

Answer (score 2):

```
# get 0 values index
zero_index = [x[0] for x in np.argwhere(array==0)]

# get value change index
data = []
for i in range(len(zero_index)-1):
    if zero_index[i] + 1 != zero_index[i+1]:
        data.append([zero_index[i]+1,zero_index[i+1]-1])

# get index to replace
n = 30
replace_index = []
for pair in data:
    if pair[1] - pair[0] < 30:
        if pair[1] - pair[0] == 0:
            replace_index.append([pair[1]])
        else:
            replace_index.append(list(range(pair[0], pair[1]+1)))


replace_index = [item for sublist in replace_index for item in sublist]
# replace data
array[replace_index] = 0
```

**Output:**

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. I used a simpler array so its easier to follow along.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1])
threshold = 3
```

First find consecutive runs

```
runs = np.r_[True,np.not_equal(x[1:],x[:-1])]
print(runs)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,
        True, False])
```

Identify where the runs start

```
start_of_runs = np.nonzero(runs)[0]
print(start_of_runs)
array([0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9])
```

Compute the length of the runs

```
length_of_runs =  np.diff(np.r_[start_of_runs,len(x)])
print(length_of_runs)
array([1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2])
```

Remember which runs are of ones

```
runs_of_ones = x[start_of_runs].astype(np.bool)
print(runs_of_ones)
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Find runs under threshold

```
find_runs = (length_of_runs < threshold) & runs_of_ones

for start, length in zip(start_of_runs[find_runs], length_of_runs[find_runs]):
    x[start:start+length] = 0
print(x)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
​
```